# Is an academic probation for not finding a research advisor in time considered "disciplinary sanction"?

Tags: application

Is an academic probation for not finding a research advisor in time considered "disciplinary sanctions by any university"?  This is asked in a graduate school application.

Does "sanction" mean penalty?

Does "disciplinary" include the issue of finding a research advisor in time?

Thanks!

Comment: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15067/listing-academic-dismissal-from-phd-in-graduate-application is very similar in that this person was not able to maintain the minimum GPA (similar to your not meeting the academic requirements). The short answer: No. Your situation does not constitute a disciplinary sanction. Voted to close, because of duplicates.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of disciplinary sanction? Thanks!

Comment: A sanction is a penalty imposed for violating a rule. A disciplinary sanction usually implies the intentional breaking of a rule. (For instance, committing plagiarism or theft.)